# why laravel view is showing blank page?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, frameworks, laravel-artisan

when I open "http://localhost/app/public/"
the default laravel home page works perfectly which is a welcome page where in the routes file there is this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });
```

but I'm learning so I just changed the "welcome" to "home" and created a new file resources/views/home.blade.php with the following simple code:

```
<?php
 echo 'hello world of laravel';
 ?>
```

but when I open "http://localhost/app/public/"

it shows a blank page.

what am i missing?

Comment: Open up your `.env` file and set `APP_DEBUG=true` to see details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup your web server so it point to `public` directory and then access the app through http://localhost/

Comment: I tried "php artisan serve" and It works but I didn't think of of this to be the issue.

Comment: can you help me setup web server so it point to public directory, I don't know how

Comment: Look here, especially Step 5: http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/ - all you need is setup VirtualHost to your Laravel's public directory and it should work (just enter http://localhost/ in browser).

Comment: I could't make a virtual host but I changed the apache directory to my application public folder. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your home.blade.php to just html, remove this

```
 <?php
 echo 'hello world of laravel';
 ?>
```

and try something like:

```
<h1> Hello, world! </h1>
```

and see if works :)

Comment: no not working, I even tried to copy the welcome.blade.php contents to home.blade.php and still not working. but I changed the apache directory to my application public folder and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution open .env file make sure no space in your app name.The app name should be one word for example AppOne not App One

Comment: You can also have `APP_NAME="App One"`.  But in principle, this answer is correct as one possible cause of the problem.